# Add strechable space in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout

I have this XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="400" >

    <StackPanel Margin="10, 10, 10, 10">

        <CheckBox Content="CheckBox" Margin="0, 0, 0, 10"/>
        <Button Content="Button" Height="30" Click="OnClick"/>

    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

which gives this output:

[image]

How can I add a stretchable space between the combo box and the button to keep one on the top, and the other on the bottom?

Thanks,
Massimo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a DockPanel (the LastChildFill is important in this case):

```
<DockPanel Margin="10, 10, 10, 10" LastChildFill="False">
    <CheckBox DockPanel.Dock="Top"  Content="CheckBox" Margin="0, 0, 0, 10"/>
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Content="Button" Height="30" Click="OnClick"/>
</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a `StackPanel` for this because a `StackPanel` will only fill the space which is needed by it's children. 
A `Grid` is better for this.

Something like this would do it.

```
<Grid Margin="10, 10, 10, 10">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <CheckBox Content="CheckBox"
              Grid.Row="0"
              Margin="0, 0, 0, 10" />
    <Button Content="Button"
            Height="30"
            Grid.Row="2"
            Click="OnClick" />
</Grid>
```

[image: Sample]